# Crontab days exceptions Linux

Tags: linux, cron

I have a crontab job that works from monday to friday, but i need it to make exceptions of an specific day, for example the January 1st, the April 11th, etc.

How can i make that exception on my crontab job?

```
* * * * 1-5 ./full-backup
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want it to run on those days in addition or do you want it to skip running on those days, or perform a different action?

Comment: no you can't.
what you could do, however, is add the exclusion date login in the file-backup script

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an `and` or `or` list sequence.

> **`man sh`:** AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more  pipelines  separated  by the  `&&`  and  `||` control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.
>
> An AND list has the form `command1 && command2`.
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns an  exit  status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form `command1 || command2`. `command2`  is  executed  if and only if `command1` returns a non-zero exit status.

If you want to exclude 2 days from your cron, lets say the first of January and April 11th, then you can do the following:

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *     command to be executed
  *  *  *  * 1-5    [ `date '+\%m\%d'` == "0101" ] || [ `date '+\%m\%d'` == "0411" ] || ./full_backup.sh
```

From the moment you have more days to exclude it becomes a bit more tricky. You could use a smaller script like `excludedaycmd`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ $1 != "" ]]; do
  [[ $(date "+%m%d" )) == $1 ]] && exit 1
  shift
done
exit 0
```

This script will exit with 1 if any of its arguments fit a day. Your cron would look then like.

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *     command to be executed
  *  *  *  * 1-5    excludedaycmd 0101 0411 && ./full_backup.sh
```

Any other script can also be used in any other form.